# Select tab by name in jquery UI 1.10.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

***Before***  *jquery UI 1.10.0* I used to indirectly select a tab like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "select", 5 );
```

or

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "select", "tab6" );
```

Now, with the same code, using *jquery UI 1.10.0* ,  you get an error saying that there is "***no such method 'select' for tabs widget instance***".

I changed the code to use the "option" "active" like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "option","active", 5 );
```

However, it looks like I can use only the index. Selecting by ID is not working anymore.
So, instead of using the ID like this (which is not working) :

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "option","active", "tab6" );
```

you have to do it like this:

```
var idx = $('#tabs a[href="#tab6"]').parent().index();
$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", idx );
```

or, in a shorter form

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", $("#tab6").parent().index() );
```

I read the "changelog" (http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.0/) and I don't see anything about this change.

Is there another way of selecting a tab by name in *jquery UI 1.10.0* ?

I created a demo here for whoever wants to try...

http://jsbin.com/ojufej/1

Comment: +1 This was one of the more irritating changes in 1.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using this (see example):

http://jsfiddle.net/AzSUS/

Basically, I added these functions

```
$.fn.tabIndex = function () {
    return $(this).parent().find(this).index() - 1; 
};
$.fn.selectTabByID = function (tabID) {
    $(this).tabs("option", "active", $('#' + tabID).tabIndex());
};
$.fn.selectTabByIndex = function (tabIndex) {
    $(this).tabs("option", "active", tabIndex);
};
```

Ans use them like this:

```
$("#tabs").selectTabByIndex(0);

$("#tabs").selectTabByID('tab2');
```

As you'll see in the HTML section on my example ...

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">[0] #tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">[1] #tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">[2] #tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">[3] #tab4</a></li>
  </ul> 
  <div id="tab1">Tab 1 Content</div>
  <div id="tab2">Tab 2 Content</div>
  <div id="tab3">Tab 3 Content</div>
  <div id="tab4">Tab 4 Content</div>
</div>
```

... I have a very simple, well defined structure for the tabs.

The "real" application contains 3 levels of tabs

See this example with 2 levels:

http://jsfiddle.net/vgaTP/

Another thing that I wasn't clear about is this: I do not want to trigger the "click" on the tab, I just want to "switch" to that tab, without click. 
For me, the "click" event loads the content of a tab and I do not want to load the content every time I "select" a tab.

Comment: This worked so much better then all of the methods in this thread. Thank you above and beyond this issue was driving me insane.

Answer (score 9):

jQuery [deprecated the `select` method in v.1.9](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-select-method)

> The `select` method has been deprecated in favor of just updating the active option. You should replace all calls to the `select` method with calls to the `option` method to change the active option.

---

[In v.1.10 they completely removed it](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.0/):

> Removed: select method. ([#7156](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7156), [7cf2719](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/7cf2719d0c406c7ff17c7e784c0e1e6eb23b562a))

---

The closest I could get to selecting a tab by name was using the `href` attribute selector and the `trigger` method.

```
$( "[href='#tab6']").trigger( "click" );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QRUGM/

---

The original `select` method did something [similar](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/7cf2719d0c406c7ff17c7e784c0e1e6eb23b562a#L1L1096):

```
this.anchors.eq( index ).trigger( this.options.event + this.eventNamespace );
```

Only they selected the tab by the index instead of the name.

Comment: I use the "click" to load the tab's content. The "select" I was talking about should just switch to that tab. I don't think though that the original "select" triggered the "click" event on the tag (I do not have time to go back and test now). I used the "select" before as I said in my question and it wasn't the same event as "click"

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a large amount of legacy code referencing these depreciated functions, and migrating is a headache, create a backwards compatibility module that bridges the old/new methods.

```
$.extend(true, $.ui.tabs.prototype, {
    select: function (indexOrId) {
        if (typeof indexOrId == "integer")
            this.option("select", indexOrId);
        else
            $("[href='#"+ indexOrId +"']", this.element).click();
    }
    // other methods..
});
```

Comment: I do not want to "click" on the tab, I just want to "select" the tab

Comment: So just integrate your index/id conversion code into that second part. The point is that you can override the prototype so that your existing code doesn't have to change, meaning you can still call: $("#tabs").tabs( "select", "tab6" );

Answer (score 1):

Really easy;

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", $("#tabs").find("#tab6").index()-1 );
```

Where **#tab6** is the ID of the tab you want to select and **#tabs** is the ID of your tab control.

Answer (score 0):

I used the above $( "[href='#tab6']").trigger( "click" ); posted by Ayman Safadi ( thanks! ) together with a hidden field and its works great. 
Big up for this post also http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2010/07/09/jquery-tab-retain-selected-tab-across-postbacks-in-asp.net.aspx which in combination with Aymens answer helped me get to this final answer :) thanks all

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var currTab = $("#<%= HFCurrTabIndex.ClientID %>").val();

        if (currTab == 0) {
            $("[href='#tab_1_1']").trigger("click");
        }

        if (currTab == 1) {
            $("[href='#tab_1_2']").trigger("click");
        }

        if (currTab == 2) {
            $("[href='#tab_1_3']").trigger("click");
        }

        if (currTab == 3) {
            $("[href='#tab_1_4']").trigger("click");
        }   

    });
</script>
```

Just to note also, the below code did work too but turned my tabs blue for some reason

```
 $('#tabs').tabs();
                   var currTab = $("#<%= HFCurrTabIndex.ClientID %>").val();
                   $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", currTab);
```