# jQuery multiple tabs + validation select does not fire (MVC3/Razor/VB)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-tabs, unobtrusive-validation

I've used [a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643500/jquery-validation-multiple-tabs-validate-one-at-a-time) ([which I've fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uuhgu/)) for restricting submission of a form until all required fields are filled.

The problem is when I run on my MVC3 project, as I've observed on Firebug, it stops starting at the third line of the following block. Because of it, the solution doesn't work.

```
    var validator = $("#myForm").validate();
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) { // Here.
            // The following lines are not executed.
            var valid = true;
            var current = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");
            var panelId = $("#tabs ul a").eq(current).attr("href");
```

Can somebody tell me why my project won't run the rest of the script and what I should do to fix it? Thanks!

In my View file

```
@ModelType SLC.Models.RegisterModel

// downloaded with NuGet
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var validator = $("#myForm").validate();
        console.log(validator);
        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var valid = false;
                var current = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");
                var panelId = $("#tabs ul a").eq(current).attr("href");

                $(panelId).find("input").each(function () {
                    console.log(valid);
                    if (!validator.element(this) && valid) {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                });

                return valid;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" />

@Using Html.BeginForm("", "", Nothing, New With {.id = "myForm"})
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    @<div>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab-1">1. Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2">2. Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-3">3. Confirm</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tab-1">
                // Some fields...
            </div>

            <div id="tab-2">
                // Some fields...
            </div>

            <div id="tab-3">
                // Some fields...

                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
End Using
```

In my Layout template file

```
<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    // downloaded with NuGet
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

The jQuery UI `select` method, in particular, is deprecated as of [1.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859281/select-tab-by-name-in-jquery-ui-1-10-0), so it's either back to UI 1.9.2 or a code rewrite.